# Como salvar quebras de linha de um textarea para o banco de dados?

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

Tenho um `textarea` e gostaria de salvar as quebras de linhas feitas pelo usuário no banco de dados. ***Por exemplo***, o usuário escreve o seguinte:

```
"Lorem Ipsum.
Is simply.
Dummy text.
Of the printing.
And typesetting."
```

Mas, no banco de dados, é salvo como:

> `"Lorem Ipsum. Is simply. Dummy text. Of the printing. And typesetting."`

Gostaria que fosse escrito com as quebras de linhas feitas no textarea.
Como posso fazer isso usando `PHP`?

Comment: As quebras de linhas foram recusadas. Mas no caso, pularia a linha a cada ponto no exemplo.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre isso aí que você disse é besteira. Não tem problema nenhum gravar quebra de linha em VARCHAR. O que muda nos formatos de texto para o usuário final basicamente é a capacidade de armazenamento.

Comment: Segue teste mostrando que o MySQL respeita as quebras ao salvar:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8938a/1

Comment: @Marcelo o problema pode não estar no salvar, mas no fato de você não trocar por <br> ao jogar de volta na tela. Precisa testar isso. Se for o caso, você salva no DB, mas na hora de RECUPERAR usa o `nl2br` como o Miguel disse.

Comment: @Bacco, verifiquei aqui e realmente me confundi com os campos input que sempre salvo como varchar e textarea que sempre salvo como text. Realmente varchar aceita sim quebra de linha \n e falei besteira quando disse que não aceitava. Nos campos de input type="text" não tem como digitar quebra de linha, mas no banco entra quebra de linha mesmo se for varchar. No entanto inserir <br> para quebrar linha no banco não é boa prática e nisso eu estava certo. Exceto se for proposital como na edição de um campo utilizado em editor WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 6):

Podes usar [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), para testar podes fazer:

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="test"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
echo nl2br($_POST['test']);
```

Vai dar um *warning* antes da primeira tentativa porque não fizeste ainda um post mas depois de submeteres já vai estar ok.

Comment: It works! E eu confesso que não conhecia essa função.

Comment: A pergunta não é minha, @miguel. Mas Eu testei porque não conhecia a função ;)

Comment: Ah, e a edição que eu sugeri era só pra evitar a falha do `$_POST` não feito ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @Marcelo se te ajudou deves aceitar a resposta. Por baixo das cima/baixo à esquerda da resposta

Comment: Não user nl2br para salvar no banco. Use o tipo de campo como text no banco de dados.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre o campo `text` não faz com que as quebras de linha se mantenham: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498461/how-to-save-user-entered-line-breaks-from-a-textarea-to-a-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729524/php-mysql-storing-line-breaks-in-text-area-in-database

Comment: @Miguel, as quebras de linha se mantém se o tipo do campo no banco de dados for text. Não aparece no html pq o html tira, mas se olhar o código fonte você percebe as quebras de linha. Mas para exibir na tela deve-se usar essa função sim. Para salvar com isso, use apenas se você só for trabalhar com html mesmo, tipo quem salva conteúdo de um editor WYSIWYG. Por exemplo: Se eu salvar com <br> e depois quiser o conteúdo pra usar em um arquivo q não seja html, vai ficar <br> poluindo o texto.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre ok, não sabia disso mas até hoje sempre fiz assim para guardar na DB, seja campo text ou não. Obgado porque realmente nao sabia

Comment: @Miguel, é isso aí, aqui é uma comunidade e todos estão aqui pra se ajudar. Como você é um usuário com bastante reputação, incremente sua resposta para ajudar mais pessoas que visitarem no futuro.

Comment: Miguel isso ai que o @AntonioAlexandre está falando é besteira, o TEXT não tem nada de diferente do VARCHAR nem do CHAR em relação a quebras de linha.

Comment: @Bacco confesso que tb achei pouco provável mas ele falou com tanta certeza que visto que ainda não tinha testado e não timha 100% certeza que nao funcionaria, quem era eu para desacordar?! Mas obgado poupaste-me uns mins de testes

Comment: @Miguel sempre faça os testes :)

Comment: @Bacco nao os fiz porque nao tenho acesso a um comp agora, mas visto que já me disseste acho desnecessário/irrelevante fazer este teste em esppecial

Comment: Segue teste mostrando as quebras salvas nos lugares corretos ;) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8938a/1

Comment: @Bacco obgado, exato mas aí introduziste-as diretamente na query, para que elas cheguem até aí, ao passar pelo servidor até à inserção temos de as manter usando a minha resposta certo?

Comment: @Miguel justamente, comentei isso na pergunta. Eu pus na query só pra mostrar que foi salvo, pois o SQL Fiddle por acaso não mostra direito a quebra também :) No caso do autor da pergunta o nl2br na hora da exibição é a provável solução mesmo. A única coisa que ele precisa ver é se capturou a string com quebra, mas aí só testando. Só não recomendo ele aplicar o nl2br ao salvar, e sim somente ao exibir. Sua resposta me parece correta, só faltou o autor ter postado o código dele para poder dar mais detalhes.

Comment: @ Bacco,  posso ter me confundindo com algo q eu falei,  na verdade com convicção agora só posso falar que o input type text que não salva quebra de linha e isso é óbvio. Mas irei fazer testes na segunda quando chegar em casa. Mas o que falei com mais convicção é que utilizar nl2br antes  de salvar no banco de dados é uma má prática,  a não ser que esteja usando um WYSIWYG e seu objetivo seja mesmo salvar html no banco. E vc acabou de concordar comigo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar a função [nl2br()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp):

Ex.:

```
echo nl2br("Essa\r\neh\n\ruma\nstring\r");
```

Output:

```
Essa<br />
eh<br />
uma<br />
string<br />
```

Ou então colocar o texto a ser gravado entre as tags `<pre></pre>`.

Ex.:

```
<pre>
Linha 1.
           Linha 2 esta a direita da linha 1.
           Linha 3 esta alinhada com a linha 2.
</pre>
```

Veja mais em [W3C Wiki - HTML/Elements/pre](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/pre)

Answer (score 1):

Não use nl2br para salvar no banco para não sujar o banco com html.
nl2br você pode usar na hora que for exibir na tela.
Exceto se o seu intuito for mesmo salvar html no banco, por exemplo, se for salvar o conteúdo de um editor WYSIWYG.

Answer (score -2):

Sei que talvez não esteja no âmbito da pergunta, mas também é uma forma de resolver o seu problema e ainda implementar uma solução mais elegante.

**Utilize um TextEditor.**

Além dele te dar uma segurança melhor, ele também te permite personalizar o texto. Veja que o próprio Stackoverflow se utiliza de Texteditor.

Existem diversos tipos de texteditor no mercado, veja qual se adequa melhor para a sua solução e implemente. Pode ser um pouco complicado no começo, mas você irá ver que a solução final irá ser bem mais elegante.